# In Elixir's ExUnit, is it possible to just run one test?

Tags: elixir

In Python's nosetests you can just specify to run one test by calling its class followed by the test name. How can we do this with Elixir's ExUnit?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can now do `mix test path/to/test.exs:13`, where 13 is the line of the test.

Comment: Actually now you can by added the line number of the test to the end of the above mix command

Comment: For umbrella project, do not include `apps/app_name` in the file path. Even if the file path from root directory is `apps/app_name/test/app_name_test.exs`, just run `mix test test/app_name_test.exs:13`. See [this](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/5650#issuecomment-272390635).

Comment: Recent Elixir versions support the full umbrella as well. :)

Answer (score 71):

Add a tag to a test (e.g. `wip`) and run with the `mix --only` flag.

```
@tag :wip
test "only run this test" do
  assert true
end
```

Run as: `mix test --only wip`

This will only run tests with the defined tag, skipping all others.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I asked the same question today on IRC and the guys answered (thanks Nhu and José) that now I can do it with mix.

You can run a single test with:

```
mix test path/to/file_test.exs:42
```

If you work with Vim, you can create a mapping [like I did here (based on vim-rspec)](https://github.com/philss/venci/blob/6b7306b83fcefc319fad087ce1d1f823dd720186/ftplugin/elixir.vim).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Amrita can run one specific test at a time:

https://github.com/josephwilk/amrita